# Save Google Maps Markers onClick To Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want your guys' help on this. I wrote the code for allowing users to create markers(with infowindow) with a 'click' function that will save the lat/lan and other info to a MySQL database that will then be called to show the markers on the map. When you click on the map, it creates a marker but it will not save the info in the infowindow to the database. I followed the guide from the google maps developer's guide but I still can't get it to work. I even triple checked to make sure my MySQL login details work correct and still nothing.

**Here is the code to the map itself:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var marker;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  var options = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
  var html = "<table>" +
             "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Type:</td> <td><select id='type'>" +
             "<option value='bar' SELECTED>bar</option>" +
             "<option value='restaurant'>restaurant</option>" +
             "</select> </td></tr>" +
             "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close'     onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: html
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
}

function saveData() {
  var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
  var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
  var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
  var latlng = marker.getPosition();

  var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
            "&type=" + type + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
  downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
      infowindow.close();
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
    }
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
</script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**This is what is supposed to save info to the database(phpsqlinfo_addrow.php):**

```
    <?php
require("phpsqlinfo_dbinfo.php");

// Gets data from URL parameters
$name = $_GET['name'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lng = $_GET['lng'];
$type = $_GET['type'];

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Insert new row with user data
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO markers " .
     " (id, name, address, lat, lng, type ) " .
     " VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');",
     mysql_real_escape_string($name),
     mysql_real_escape_string($address),
     mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
     mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
     mysql_real_escape_string($type));

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: first wrong in url 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? sensor=false"></script>
Shulod be <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

Comment: What's the console saying?

Comment: @alkis it's not giving me any error messages so I don't know what to fix.

Answer (score 1):

hi i have same issue with my project to save customer location,
which they click on there browser,
what i did was i save location in latitude and longitude in two input box as{you may take it hidden so it will not seen} in  and give submit button and submit form i have given code you can also change it to submit form on click on map by submitting form on click by this and you can also store latitude and longitude in same column if you want

and you will need to insert you key

```
document.getElementById("yourform").submit();



<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
              #map_canvas {height:300px;width:500px}
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=""""youerapikeyhere""""&language=mr"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var marker;
        var markersArray = [];
        function initialize()
        {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.5236, 73.8478);
                var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    if (marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);    //code          
    }
        //adding marker
    document.getElementById('txtLat').value=event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('txtLng').value=event.latLng.lng();
      marker= new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'pune'
  });
      //creting info window instance
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'selected location'
  });
      //adding pointer click event to open infowindow
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr><td colspan=3><div id="map_canvas" style="background-color: #ffffff"></div></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" id="txtLat" name="txtLat"style="width:150px"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtLng" name="txtLng"style="width:150px"></td></tr>
        </table></form>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow down the possibilities, or at least find out "where" it went wrong; meaning, is the issue caused from the front end or in the backend!?

If you use Webkit UA (browser) or its variants, use its Developer tools; if using Firefox, install an AddOn called FireBug. In the marker's click handler, try to output the coordinates using alert() or console.log() and see if the results are accurately fetched. Next check whether the AJAX call is passed as it should be to the backend.

In your PHP, try to examine the incoming values (from request parameters). Also turn on the debug output in php.ini so you'll know if the DB connections are successfully made by checking stderr or system logs.

There's a lot of things that could go wrong. It's hard to tell given by the lack of details you provided, but I hope my reply helps you to get a good start.

Oh, BTW, I'd strongly suggest you switch to PDO over mysql_*, the mysql_* are to be deprecated in the future.